# Configuring Webrick in rails 3.0 to serve both http and https (SSL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, webrick

I am trying to use ssl_requiremnt plugin for rails 3.0 in my app. A few links in my app need to be secure with SSL and the rest need to be served by http only. I configured webrick according to this post: http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/chris_rohr/configuring_webrick_to_use_ssl.html

Now I want webrick to serve both http and https. It seems it was easy with rails 2.3.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: does not seem to to possible. if i say 'require webrick/https' then it stops responding to http.

Comment: yes it seems it is not possible to set https with webrick I used Nginx instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by switching Nginx but could not do it using Webrick. I guess Webrick does not support two instances of a server simultaneously and to switch you need to stop the current server and restart the server which has got https:// settings.