# Rails with thin and ssl: http request not auto-redirected to https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https, thin

Recently I wanted to secure my rails 4.2.1 app with https **the easiest way**. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8062030/1869446) as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11023166/1869446) about WEBrick+SSL, both referencing to [this post](http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/chris_rohr/configuring_webrick_to_use_ssl.html) which is unfortunately not reachable any more. Then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22878130/1869446) recommending to use thin instead (naming other advantages of using thin). Then I followed [this](http://makandracards.com/makandra/15903-using-thin-for-development-with-ssl) step-by-step guide, finally running `thin start --ssl --ssl-key-file .ssl/key.pem --ssl-cert-file .ssl/cert.pem -e production` with self-signed certificate. My `config/environments/production.rb` contains `config.force_ssl = true`.

Now I would like to access the web normally by typing `example.com` expecting to be **automatically redirected** to `https://example.com` but **this does not happen**. Typing looong `https://example.com` works fine. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17009803/1869446) is a 2-year-old question with similar issue but any answer doesn't work either and something could have also changed since then.

How can I make it work? Or is there any different recent but simple enough way to start using ssl with rails? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In your **config/environment/production.rb** file make sure you have the following:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

Also make sure to update your cookie settings in **config/initializers/session_store.rb**:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_secure_domain_session', httponly: true, secure: true
```

You also need to specify `secure: true` in the **config/initializers/devise.rb** file if you are using Devise

Also make sure to clear the cache on your browser

Comment: config/environments/production.rb - check, config/initializers/session_store.rb - check, I'm not using devise, browser cache - check, thin restarted - of course. Still not automatically redirecting to https :(

Comment: Why I don't have those issues on ngrok?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a load balancer in front of your website that is terminating the TLS/SSL and then connecting via HTTPS to the backend, this would mean the connection from the load balancer to your server *is* HTTPS, even though the client connection to the load balancer is not. Your load balancer *should* send the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header which Rails should take into account.

If you are running Rails under Passenger inside Nginx (or Apache), you may need to configure that to forward the header and/or port.

```
passenger_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
passenger_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
```

Note, however, that Rails looks [first at the `HTTPS` environment variable before it looks at the header](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1-6-stable/lib/rack/request.rb#L69), and that might be set to `"on"` because connection to your web server is HTTPS.

In that case you can redirect all traffic from HTTP to HTTPS [inside Nginx](https://serverfault.com/a/824170):

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
}
```